# Recomputing a struct for a quiz game

Tags: swift, swiftui

I am very new to Swift (I started 5 days ago), and I am working on my first app. I'm almost finished with it. It lets you listen to chords, and you can take a quiz to test your relative pitch ability. However, the quiz only works once, because when the quiz ends, it retains the same questions, and my index variable for the questions goes out of range. Thus I decided to make a function that resets the Answers that can be called by my QuizViewModel after the quiz is finished. However, I'm having some trouble figuring out the logic. I made a function in my Answer model, but it doesn't seem to carry over to my Quiz Model. Here are the models in question:

Answer model

```
import Foundation

let roots = ["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G"]
let chordType = ["Major", "Minor"]

func chooseChord() -> String {
    let randomRoot = roots.randomElement()!
    let randomType = chordType.randomElement()!
    let randomChord = randomRoot + randomType
    return randomChord
}

func genAnswer() -> (String, [String]) {
    var answers = [String]()
    while answers.count < 4 {
        let randChord = chooseChord()
        if !answers.contains(randChord) {
            answers.append(randChord)
        }
    }
    let correctAnswer = answers.randomElement()!
    return (correctAnswer, answers)
}

struct Answer {
    private var correctAnswer: String
    private var possibleAnswers: [String]
    
    func getCorrectAnswer() -> String {
        return correctAnswer
    }
    
    func getPossibleAnswers() -> [String] {
        return possibleAnswers
    }
    
    init() {
        let answer = genAnswer()
        self.correctAnswer = answer.0
        self.possibleAnswers = answer.1
    }
    
    static var allAnswers: [Answer] = [
        Answer(),
        Answer(),
        Answer(),
        Answer(),
        Answer()
    ]
    
    func resetAnswers() {
        var newAnswers = [Answer]()
        for _ in 1...Answer.allAnswers.count {
            let new = Answer.init()
            newAnswers.append(new)
        }
        Answer.allAnswers = newAnswers
    }
}
```

Quiz model

```
import Foundation

class Quiz {
    private var rounds = Answer.allAnswers
    private var currentRoundIndex = 0
    
    var currentRound: Answer {
        return rounds[currentRoundIndex]
    }
    
    var totalRounds: Int {
        rounds.count - 1
    }
    
    func advanceRound() {
        let nextRoundIndex = currentRoundIndex + 1
        currentRoundIndex = nextRoundIndex
    }
    
    func reset() {
        Answer.resetAnswers()
        currentRoundIndex = 0
    }
```

QuizViewModel

```
import Foundation

class QuizViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var game = Quiz()
    
    var correctAnswerText: String {
        game.currentRound.getCorrectAnswer()
    }
    
    func answerText() -> [String] {
        game.currentRound.getPossibleAnswers()
    }
    
    var totalRounds: Int {
        return game.totalRounds
    }
    
    func advanceGame() {
        game.advanceRound()
    }
}
```

Here is the full Git repo if you are interested: https://github.com/aabagdi/Chord-Helper

Thanks for your help!

Comment: why do you want to make allanswers static? I don't think changes to static variable will work with @Published property.   Just handle resetanswers in quiz model .

Comment: @andylee I did try removing static, but it gave me an infinite recursion error.

Comment: remove allanswers and reset answers from Anwer struct completely and handle them in Quiz struct.

Comment: @andylee Oh duh, that makes perfect sense! It works now, thanks!